# SQL Select Multiple field from a table from anothers tables

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm trying to select from a table some fields from anothers tables.

```
table: services

+------+------+-------+----------+----------+----------+
| id_s | serv | id_ve | destiny1 | destiny2 | destiny3 |
+------+------+-------+----------+----------+----------+
|    1 |   25 |    1  |        3 |        4 |        5 |
|    2 |   27 |    3  |        2 |        3 |        5 |
|    3 |   35 |    1  |        5 |        3 |        1 |
|    4 |   39 |    2  |        2 |        1 |        5 |
+------+------+-------+----------+----------+----------+

table: destiny

+------+---------+
| id_d | destiny |
+------+---------+
|    1 |     UK  |
|    2 |     FR  |
|    3 |     PT  |
|    4 |     SP  |
|    5 |     NL  |
+------+---------+

table: vessel

+------+---------+
| id_v | vessel  |
+------+---------+
|    1 |  Icarus |
|    2 |   Creta |
|    3 |  Dedalo |
+------+---------+
```

I'd like a result like this:

```
+------+------+--------+----------+----------+----------+
| id_s | serv | vessel | destiny1 | destiny2 | destiny3 |
+------+------+--------+----------+----------+----------+
|    1 |   25 | Icaro  | PT       | SP       | NL       |
|    2 |   27 | Dedalo | FR       | PT       | NL       |
|    3 |   35 | Icaro  | NL       | PT       | UK       |
|    4 |   39 | Creta  | FR       | UK       | NL       |
+------+------+--------+----------+----------+----------+
```

I'm trying the next sentence...

```
SELECT *
FROM `services`, `destiny`, `vessel`
WHERE `vessel`.`id_v' = `services`.`id_ve`
       AND `destiny`.`id_d` = `services`.`destiny1`
       AND `destiny`.`id_d` = `services`.`destiny2`
       AND `destiny`.`id_d` = `services`.`destiny3`
ORDER BY `services`.`id_s`
```

But I don't get expected result.

Can you please help. Your help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You need a join for each destiny attribute

Comment: As @MKhalidJunaid said, you need a separate reference and join for each. MySQL is comparing rows, not collecting them, so no no single `destiny` row's d_id can match more than one `destinyN` value (you could get results for `services` rows with all three destinyN values the same). I can't emphasize enough that you should use explicit JOIN syntax; the implicit comma-join has been out of favor for a decade or so now for a number of good reasons.

Comment: .@ArrasparusSantoro consider taking a look at my answer, not for being the right one (someone posted first and they deserve it) but consider the standards I'm trying to tell you

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 20 years.

Comment: It is _usually_ wrong to splay an array (destiny1/2/3) across columns.  If there are, and always will be, exactly 3, then OK.  Otherwise, consider having another table, which will actually shrink the number of `JOINs` needed!

Answer (score 0):

You need to join to destiny for each column in server

```
SELECT s.id_s,
       s.serv,
       v.vessel,
       d1.destiny destiny1,
       d2.destiny destiny2,
       d3.destiny destiny3
  FROM services s
 INNER
  JOIN destiny d1
    ON s.distiny1 = d1.id_d
 INNER
  JOIN destiny d2
    ON s.distiny2 = d2.id_d
 INNER
  JOIN destiny d3
    ON s.distiny3 = d3.id_d
 INNER
  JOIN vessel v
    ON s.id_ve = v.id_v
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use left join and fetch result like this

```
SELECT s.id_s,  s.serv,  v.vessel, d1.destiny destiny1, d2.destiny destiny2, d3.destiny destiny3
  FROM services s
 LEFT JOIN destiny d1
    ON s.distiny1 = d1.id_d
 LEFT JOIN destiny d2
    ON s.distiny2 = d2.id_d
 LEFT JOIN destiny d3
    ON s.distiny3 = d3.id_d
 LEFT JOIN vessel v
    ON s.id_ve = v.id_v;
```

Comment: Note: `LEFT` suggests that the matching rows in `destiny` and/or `vessel` may be missing.

Answer (score 0):

Root cause is the `WHERE` condition below, you are joining the destiny table only once and comparing single id from destiny table to three different columns of `services` which will never be true-

```
AND `destiny`.`id_d` = `services`.`destiny1`
       AND `destiny`.`id_d` = `services`.`destiny2`
       AND `destiny`.`id_d` = `services`.`destiny3`
```

You need to join the destiny table for each destiny column in the services. By the way, you are using outdated `JOIN` syntax, you should be using new syntax [ANSI-92 SQL syntax](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ProgrammersGuide/Queries/TheANSIJoinSyntax.htm%3FTocPath%3DProgrammer's%2520Guide%7CWriting%2520Queries%7CJoins%7C_____1).  @Error_2346 answered with correct query.

Answer (score 0):

There `where` condition only limits the ammount of result. What you require is, like previous answers here, is to add more joins in order for each `destinyX_id` to relate to another one.

[Here's a fiddle about it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2aea68/2)

```
select services.id_s, 
       services.serv, 
       vessel.vessel, 
       destiny1.destiny, 
       destiny2.destiny, 
       destiny3.destiny
from services
inner join vessel on vessel.id_v = services.id_ve
inner join destiny destiny1 on destiny1.id_d = services.destiny1
inner join destiny destiny2 on destiny2.id_d = services.destiny2
inner join destiny destiny3 on destiny3.id_d = services.destiny3;
```

> Allow me to say this in order to further develop you: These name conventions are incredibly horrible to read.

1. Destiny table has a destiny field. This is a destination, not someone's destiny.
2. Destiny field means what? Coords? Name? Value? Geolocation? Some random string? A number? It isn't clear
3. Same case of Destiny applies to Vessel
4. Services table - you either set the tables in singular or plural. You didn't create "vessels", you created "vessel". Same for "Destiny". Why "Services"? What do you even consider a Service?
5. Services table has id_ve. What is id_ve?
6. Services table has destiny1, destiny2, destiny3. They are foreign keys, we know that, but how is it explicit that they are foreign keys? Why don't they follow the same structure you gave to id_ve and say id_destination?

[This is a decent name structure for your tables, please take consideration into it in order to improve your development.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5fb15f/7)

Allow me to exemplify:

1. Each table has their own id. Meaning, when you see id, you know that's the table primary key. When you have something_id, you know it's a foreign key related to something's table primary key
2. Each table that has foreign keys, will have their most-possible explicit 
   relation_name_key with id at the end of the name.
3. After keys have been set, place the columns you require and leave the dates (created_at_, updated_at, etc) to the end.
4. snake_case_for_tables_and_columns
5. Each table be to their own singular purpose (or plural, personal preference). A table that is called destination contains a bunch of destinations. A table called service contains a list of services. A table called vessel contains a list of vessels.

> For future reference, you should know that inner join is enforcing relation between tables. If one of the fields of `destination` in `service` is null (column nullable), you won't get results. Consider checking left or right join, to fulfill your needs.
>   https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Thanks for all your advice. All tables were a example, they are not a real develop but all code helped me to resolve my trouble. Thanks Again!